# Restrict nodejs endpoints to the client-side application

Tags: node.js

After the initial load, an angularjs/nodejs application will use "ajax" to communicate with the server.

For example, if you have a blog app, you'll have a `POST` with the title, body, etc. Or you'll have a `GET` request that retrieves a json array of recent blog posts.

These server-side endpoints are essentially an API - they accept and return data.

How can I restrict access to these endpoints to only *my* application? A user could easily copy the url and use a server-side language or curl to use it freely.

We have an actual API, but you need an api key to use it.

Answer (score 0):

Do you authenticate users? If so, you can use session cookies to restrict access to the resources. [Mean.io](http://mean.io/#!/) shows you a very basic implementation of this function where an angular app can only access server resources when a user is logged in.

Also, are you using any nodejs frameworks? (express, resitfy, etc)

Comment: Essentially, no, users are not always authenticated. People can use basic functionality without logging in. I'm using express, passport, mongoose and a handful of smaller libs server-side, angularjs client-side.

Comment: Best idea I can think of is to set expiring session cookies. While a savvy user could find a way to pass cookie information onto a request, they will still need to send a GET request in order to get a new cookie once it expires. Another option would be to just emit data over websockets. This could turn it into a push model rather than pull model, where you send data down a socket connection. On disconnect, a use would have to send a new GET request to reconnect. Could you perhaps provide more insight as to why it would be a problem for users to access your server data outside of your web app?

Comment: Specifically, those users who are unauthenticated.